# Parameters to thread Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

Trying to use class variables in thread and getting EXC_BAS_ACCESS.
Code snippet:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {    
    NSString* accountLoginName;
    NSString* accountPassword; 
}
```

in implementation:

```
accountLoginName = [NSString stringWithString:textFieldLoginName.text];
accountPassword = [NSString stringWithString:textFieldPassword.text];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loginAtBackgroundSelector:) withObject:nil]; 


-(void)loginAtBackgroundSelector:(UIAlertView*)alert
{   
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@\n%@", accountLoginName, accountPassword);
    [self login];
    [self dismissAlert:alert];
    [pool release];
}
```

just trying to write to console and getting error in this part of code, but error in the loginAtBackgroundSelector appears from time to time.

```
-(AlertType)login
{
     NSLog(@"%@\n%@", accountLoginName, accountPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in interface:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {    
    NSString* accountLoginName;
    NSString* accountPassword; 
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* accountLoginName;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* accountPassword;
```

And this in the implementation (in the place where you assign the values):

```
self.accountLoginName = [NSString stringWithString:textFieldLoginName.text];
self.accountPassword = [NSString stringWithString:textFieldPassword.text];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loginAtBackgroundSelector:) withObject:nil];
```

Additionaly in the dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [accountLoginName release];
    [accountPassword release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Let me know if it helps.